# shell_exec/youtube-dl has incomplete output

Tags: php, shell, youtube

I have seen the other questions which are almost similar to this one but none is actually similar and none of them is helping.

I am trying to run

```
shell_exec("youtuble-dl -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UrQJFKVRN8");
```

This works as expected when I run from command line but when I access the php file from a browser it seems to "stop running" somewhere.

This is the (desired) output I get when I run `php -f file.php` from command line

```
[youtube] 5UrQJFKVRN8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 5UrQJFKVRN8: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 5UrQJFKVRN8: Extracting video information
[youtube] 5UrQJFKVRN8: Downloading embed webpage
[download] Destination: AKA - Caiphus Song.mp4
[download] 100% of 26.72MiB in 00:00
```

And this is the output I get from browser

```
[youtube] 5UrQJFKVRN8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 5UrQJFKVRN8: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 5UrQJFKVRN8: Extracting video information
[youtube] 5UrQJFKVRN8: Downloading embed webpage
```

The YouTube video is not getting copied when I access the file via browser.
The same happens if I use `exec` or `passthru` functions

Comment: Don't forget that the server your using (i.e. apache) may be running as a different user to the one that you use from the cli.  It may be that it's failing with file permissions when you try and save the file.

Comment: This happens for most videos but for some videos it works perfectly

Comment: Are you sure it's not exceeding your set `max_execution_time`?